# NETTY EventloopExecutor

Tags: java, performance, netty, netty-socketio

This is my `childhandler`. All seems to work fine but when I start load testing at 60 users and 30 concurrently after about 3 minutes the server starts rejecting my connections. Any ideias on how to fix this?
I'm using [Locust](https://locust.io/) for load testing.

```java
public class CspNettySocketServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    
    // ===========================================================
    // 1. define a separate thread pool to execute handlers with
    //    slow business logic. e.g database operation
    // ===========================================================
    final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1500); //thread pool of 1500

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)); // https://netty.io/4.1/api/index.html?io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html
        pipeline.addLast(new ByteArrayDecoder()); // add without name, name auto generated
        pipeline.addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder()); // add without name, name auto generated

        //===========================================================
        // 2. run handler with slow business logic 
        //    in separate thread from I/O thread
        //===========================================================
        pipeline.addLast(group, "serverHandler", new CspNettyServerHandle()); 
        //pipeline.addLast(new CspNettyServerHandle());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does rejecting mean here ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Thanks for your reply. Was closing the channel eventExecutor whenever a channel throws an exception. But it is all fine. Thank you